# Sharepoint 2013 News feed web part giving 404

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, administration, central-administration

SharePoint 2013 news Feed is giving following error
"SharePoint returned the following error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Contact your system administrator for help in resolving this problem."[image]

Comment: You have  to Configure mysite properly

Comment: i had configured MY site

Comment: i referred the following link to create MY Site technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.15).aspx–  Abhidec1